# 'User' object has no attribute 'notifications'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Can anyone explain why I got this error:
'User' object has no attribute 'notifications'

I have new model Notification and write in file context_processors.py next one:

```
def notifications(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        count = request.user.notifications.filter(is_viewed=False).count()
        return {
            'notifications_count': count
        }
    else:
        return dict()

def notify(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        notifications = Notification.objects.all()
        return {
            'notifications': notifications
        }
    else:
        return dict()
```

My model Notification in the same app that is a User and my models looks like this:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    class Roles(models.IntegerChoices):
        ......


class Notification(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', models.CASCADE)
    message = models.TextField('Message', max_length=250, default=None)
    is_viewed = models.BooleanField('Seen', default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.message}"

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'MSG'
        verbose_name_plural = 'MSG'
        ordering = ['-created_at',]
```

Please help me to unserstand what is the problem with User object in context_processors.py

Comment: `request.user.notification_set.filter(is_viewed=False).count()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you did not specify a [**`related_name=…`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) for the `ForeignKey` from `Notification` to `User`, the default name is `modelname_set`, so in this case `notification_set`.

You thus can access the notifications with:

```
count = request.user.notification_set.filter(is_viewed=False).count()
```

Or you can set the `related_name=…` to:

```
class Notification(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        'User',
        models.CASCADE,
        related_name='notifications'
    )
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Answer (score 3):

you dont have `related_name` and default related_name is `notification_set`.

Add related_name:

```
user = models.ForeignKey('User', models.CASCADE, related_name"notifications")
```

Or change queryset

```
count = request.user.notification_set.filter(is_viewed=False).count()
```